# undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I got below error on Ubuntu 18 when trying to install rest-client `sudo gem install rest-client`:

```
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.6/ext/unf_ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20191111-4360-816cyg.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lstdc++... no
creating Makefile

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.6/ext/unf_ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /usr/local/bin/make:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/make:23:in `<main>'

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.6/ext/unf_ext
make "DESTDIR="
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /usr/local/bin/make:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/make:23:in `<main>'

make failed, exit code 1
```

Tried installing `gcc`, `ruby-dev`, `make` but it didn't help!
Anyone could help me?

Comment: I know you're on Ubuntu and not OSX, but this thread might be useful for you: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually,

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

should work.

Comment: need to remove `/usr/local/bin/make` also